# Am i using right append function in Linked list, using python?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am learning linked lists by doing assignments, and the code for making a Linked list is working fine. But, manipulating it is not working properly. So, I have a Linked list with a head and I created a function that takes two arguments (head, how many the last numbers you want to append in the first).
The purpose of the function is, suppose you have a linked list.
1 -> 4->5->6->2->3->9
I want the last three numbers to be on the first and the remaining first 4 numbers to come at the last of these three numbers like this.
2->3->9->1 -> 4->5->6
So, what should I need is to have broken the link between 2 and its previous number(i.e, 6) and link 6.next to None and then connect 9.next to 1, to get the desired result. But, I am having some issues in the code it is running infinite time and a little bit wrong. Can you please take a look into this and help me?
Thank you

```
class Node:  # Class will intantiate a node object
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data  # node have a data
        self.next = None  # node have a link as well ( of the next node), which is None currently.
```

```
def typeinput(a):
    lis = [int(ele) for ele in a.split()]
    head = None
    tail = None
    count = 0
    for curele in lis:
        if curele == -1:
            break
        newnode = Node(curele)
        if head is None:
            head = newnode
            tail = newnode
        else:
            tail.next = newnode
            tail = newnode

    return head
```

```
def printll(head):
    while head is not None:
        print(str(head.data) + "->", end="")
        head = head.next
    print("None")
```

```
def length(head):  # This function is used for determining the lenght of the Linked List
    c = 0
    while head is not None:
        c += 1
        head = head.next
    return c
```

```
def appendN(head, n):
    count = length(head) - n  #it will give me the index of first last digit we want to break and append on first.
    i = 0
    tail = head         #we don't want to change head so, we made a tail which will keep increasing till i<count.
    if count < 0 or count > length(head):           #if count less than 0 or greater than length 
        print(f"Please enter the number between 0 to {length(head)}")
        return
    while i < count:          #loop run until we reach previous of the first last no. we want to append
        tail = tail.next
        i += 1
    headT = tail  #as we find that number we assigned it to new head
    tail.next = None #this tail.next is of head so we make it None

    while headT.next is not None:        # we will make loop and assign the head to the last numbers.next 
        headT = headT.next
    headT.next = head
    return headT
```

```
lis = "9 8 7 7 6 5 4 3 3 2 1"
head = typeinput(lis)
c = appendN(head, 3)
printll(c)
```

I hope you get the Idea what I am trying to do here

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags. This has nothing to do with DSA (digital signature algorithm).

Comment: I thought it is stand for DATA STRUCTURE AND ALGORITHM 
Apologies

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try another implementation like the following. Note that this code works even with negative integer `n` values, so if you enter -3 as a parameter, the LinkedList will shift on the opposite direction, avoiding issues and exceptions:

```
def appendN(head, n):
    if not head:
        return
    size = 1
    tail = head
    while tail.next:
        size += 1
        tail = tail.next

    tail.next = head
    for i in range(-n % size):
        tail = tail.next
    head = tail.next
    tail.next = None
    return head
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the operation you're attempting (which I would call a right-rotation, not an "append"), by keeping track of two node references that you advance together through the list, `n` nodes apart.

```
def appendN(head, n):
    tail = new_tail = head  # initialize two references into the list
    for _ in range(n):      # advance the first one n times
        if not tail.next:
            raise ValueError("Linked list is too short") # or print and return
        tail = tail.next

    while tail.next:      # then advance both in lockstep until you reach the end
        tail = tail.next
        new_tail = new_tail.next

    tail.next = head      # link the end of the list to the beginning
    head = new_tail.next  # grab a reference to the new head
    new_tail.next = None  # and split the list where the second reference ended up

    return head
```